# Any server like selenium rc?

Tags: php

Do you know any server like Selenium RC? I'm using xampp on Windows, I cant run Selenium on my LocalHost.
I want to use php language.

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampplite\htdocs\robot\GoogleTest.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampplite\php\PEAR;./PEAR/') in C:\xampplite\htdocs\robot\GoogleTest.php on line 5
```

Where is the PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php, I don't know.

OK, final step. I got this error while installing phpunit:

```
    C:\xampplite\php>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is
 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/DbUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is
1.9.0
phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed vers
ion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed v
ersion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleToo
ls" (version >= 1.6)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/File_Iterator" (version >= 1.
2.2)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2
.0.5)
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed
 version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed v
ersion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed ve
rsion is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTool
s" (version >= 1.6)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Comment: i don't know. it's not working. there is not any usage guide. so poor

Comment: @shameless_jo How do you know it's not working. An error message or description of the specific issue would be a start.

Comment: @mike i added error message to my question.

Comment: The error message references a file that's part of PHPUnit. Have you installed phpunit?

Comment: @mike no. i only installed php pear+selenium. what's phpunit. there's not any installing guide for selenium. they only give rar files. so poor. let me install phpunit

Comment: @shameless there is an installing guide, at least to some extent: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: @shameless_jo I updated my answer to try to take care of the latest error message. PHPUnit has a few dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests that PHPUnit is not installed. You can install it via pear:

```
pear channel-update pear.php.net
pear upgrade-all
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Selenium is a language-agnostic tool. You need to look up tutorials/guides for installing selenium with PHP. The most well-known implementation is through PHPUnit. Which makes sense because PHPUnit is a testing framework and Selenium is just another method of testing.

Here is PHPUnit's guide on installing phpunit/selenium: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html

Comment: you are the best :) you know this job. you are a guru. thanks for million times. you helped me very well. i love you stackoverflow :)